# How to specify mime-type mappings when using s3cmd sync?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I want to synchronise files from a location in Perforce to an S3 bucket.  I've set up a Jenkins job that uses s3cmd to sync files from Perforce to S3.

The problem I'm having is that the auto-detection of mime-types is not working as I would like.  Is there a relatively straightforward way to override the detection with my own mime-type mapping?  Let's say I want all `.xml.gz` files to be mime-typed as `application/x-gzip`.

How do I do this without rolling my own equivalent of s3cmd sync?  Is there a way to do this with s3cmd, or is there another tool that's good for syncing a folder to S3 that has this functionality?

**EDIT:**

This isn't what I was looking for, but if anyone else has the problem it at least gets past the issue. I modified `S3.py` and after the snippet that looks like this:

```
if not content_type:
    content_type = self.config.default_mime_type
```

I added:

```
# JUN-DAI'S HACK TO GET .gz mimetypes correct.
# I couldn't find another way to do this as the mimetypes library strips out the ".gz" suffix and determines the mimetype of the underlying file without it.
if filename.endswith(".gz"):
    content_type = "application/x-gzip"
    print "Setting content-type of {0} to {1}".format(filename, content_type)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but as a note for any future people with this problem: I ended up making a 2-line change to the s3cmd code to get this working :-(

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Care to share the change?

Comment: @#$@$! stackoverflow comments! I will post it as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the options `--no-guess-mime-type --default-mime-type "application/x-gzip"` with s3cmd sync or put.

Comment: I got the error `--no-guess-mime-type: command not found` recently

Comment: Use `--no-mime-magic`